# How to encrypt whole json data using s/mime and x509 certificate

Tags: java, rest, jboss

i am not familiar with cryptography,there is requirement in my project that i have to send json data in encrypted form that is using s/mime or x509 certificate.i am using resteasy 
Please help me 
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have to use SSL - HTTPS. It shouldn't matter for your Java App what transmission is used but your JBoss admins must set up connectors/listeners - usually 8443 and install SSLs.